# Unable to retrieve value of the gridview column after making it invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview say gv1 . Which has 5 columns. I bind the gridview on the change of a dropdown selection. After binding I make the 4th(gv1.column[3]) and 5th(gv1.column[4])column visible false.

```
gv1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
gv1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

I am unable to access the column value(these are id's) later.
I tried making it visible before accessing still in vain.

```
{
    gv1.Columns[3].Visible = True;
    gv1.Columns[4].Visible = True;

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim());
}
```

I get the error at 'id' "Input string was not in a correct format."
I found ,All the column for each value is having null value.

Comment: Have you tried DataKeyValue of ur grid

Comment: Is it posible to have it for two columns. I need the value to both the columns but it should not be visible.

Comment: check the page for the GridView (HTML View Source) whethear the Gridview has been rendered or not. Kindly let me know

Comment: I think you can't have it for two columns

Answer (score 1):

Hai avi,

Look at this it may be useful [GridViewHideColumn](http://www.netomatix.com/development/GridViewHideColumn.aspx) and access its value..

Comment: This is fair enough. Instead of hiding the whole grid. we can hide particular cell on the RowDataBound event. Pretty cool.

Comment: dont know. but this is the good way of approaching that requirement.

Comment: Hey buds ...I was not able to get the result with the style sheets.
But did a crap workaround which is working fine for my requirements. I just changed the color of the columns to the background colour , he he he ... Those two columns became invisible.Tried color illusion ha ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one work around.

Because when you set the grid visibility in the server side as INVISIBLE.

The gridview wont be rendered in during the next post back.

So Keep the Grid view in the Div tag. And make the DIV tag style invisible.

So that you can access the gridview value as you like @ the sametime the grid is not visible to the page users.

....

Comment: @solairaja You want her to use style.visibility="hidden" or style.display="none" for the div..

Comment: Yeah but I just need to make two columns invisible not the Whole GridView.

Comment: @solairaj this was the prob i thought

Comment: Why can't I make the colums visible just before accessing the value. In any case I'm making the column invisible after binding.

Comment: This way     gv1.Columns[3].Visible = True;    gv1.Columns[4].Visible = True;    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim());

Comment: i thougt that the requirment is hiding the whole gridview.